# Is there an in-universe explanation in the 90s Iron Man cartoon as to why he can summon his special suits?

Tags: marvel, iron-man, weapon, armor

Tony Stark can summon his suits (and in the fighting video games where he appears, his weapons) that aren't nearby (i.e. you don't see him telling JARVIS to have them on standby or to follow him).

Is any in-universe explanation for this?

Comment: Do you want it addressing just the 90's cartoon or the games / both?

Comment: @DoctorWho22 both, preferably. The movies, i happen to know are in a different universe (one similar to our own that follow the same laws of physics, which wouldn't allow such a thing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to answer this as best as I can considering I'm not too well versed in Iron Man as far as the comics/TV show goes.  Based on quick research Iron Man as far back as the early 80's/90's has had control over his suits using various means.

In the early 80's the Space Armor Mk 1 was controlled through a cybernetic interface. Eventually he combined this technology with a Telepresence Neural Net.

From [the wikia](https://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Iron_Man_Armor_Model_12) on Armor model 12:

> Telepresence Neural Net transmits mental commands from a headset via
>   sub-space. This system gives the wearer realistic feeling without lag
>   time, but also makes him or her vulnerable to feedback.

[image: Iron Man armor model 12]

When the 90's hit he started using Modular Armor.

From [the wikia](https://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Iron_Man_Armor_Model_13) for the Iron Man Armor model 13:

> This armor was a modular component system rather than a fully
>   integrated suit. As such, each individual system (helmet, boots etc.)
>   may have had different features. There were also plug-in points for
>   various modules. One of these was the Hulkbuster add-on used when Hulk
>   confronted Iron Man over the production of gamma bombs when part of
>   Stane International.

[image: Iron Armor model 13]

It's safe to assume that using the various technology he had implemented allowed him to summon suits from a distance. The Telepresence Neural Net could be used to send a signal for summoning entire suits or even parts for the modular suit as well.

According to Wikipedia they state that the armor in the animated TV show in the 90's and the MVC game series are the Modular Armor.

Comment: I'll give it a day or so to allow others to answer the question. If they give more research / a more detailed answer, they'll get the point(s). If not, you'll get it for the accepted answer.

Comment: I totally understand I had trouble searching for Iron Man summon stuff on google in general. I widened the search to Iron Man armor in general and found the information pertaining to the Telepresence Neural Net, I'd honestly have to look up the comics for the original Modular Armor or rewatch the old series in general.